# DataGridView Rows AutoSize Not Working on Painted Strings

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When using the CellPainting event to draw strings of values assigned to a DataGridView, I can't determine how to get the height of these cells to make row height updates to show the strings automatically.

I've tried using the GetPreferredHeight method, but it is always returning 20 instead of a height that needed to show the multiple strings drawn with the CellPainting event.

Comment: Follow the code in, e.g., here: [HIghlight specific characters in all Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419493/7444103)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I found the Measure String to be useful.  I still burned through a third day on this issue and haven't quite got it resolved.  I'm using poor practices, like a form-level _maxRowHeight that I update in each thisCellPainting event, for setting Row.Height in the RowPostPaint event.  Hopefully today, I will figure out the right and bottom border piece. Since they're drawn in each cell, the columns prior to the one that is tallest that force the row taller, are drawn at the earlier _maxRowHeight...maybe reverting to CellBounds for lines will work  after RowPostPaint update.