# Make text in ReadOnly DataGridViewCell selectable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi I'm currently working on a project, where I have a windows forms with a DataGridView.
The user should not be able to change the values of a cell but it was requested, that a single word from a sentence is selectable. Because the cell is set as ReadOnly this is not possible and it selects the whole cell.

I'm not familiar with Windows Forms and I'm not able to use anything else than a DataGridView is there a solution for my problem?

Current:
[image]

Goal:
[image]

Comment: I assume you can set it as `editable`, but suppress edit in `OnKeyPress` event handler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005624/14171304

Comment: [Highlight specific characters in all Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419493/7444103)